# Foreign key in django returns all data from related model

Tags: database, django

I have two `Model` classes,  `A` and `B`. `B` has a `ForeignKey` to `A`.

Both models have a corresponding `ModelForm`.

When I do this:

```
bbb = BForm();
for b in bbb:
    print b;
```

If `b` is a `ForeignKey` field it prints a combobox with all data from the database (from class `A`).

Why?

Comment: Can we have models example? ForeignKey OneToOne? OneToMany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Django `ModelForms` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types):

> `ForeignKey` is represented by `django.forms.ModelChoiceField`, which is a `ChoiceField` whose choices are a model QuerySet.

[`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField) is rendered using `select` tag by default.

Comment: Ok, but why have all data from A?

Comment: @user3133314, **whose choices are a model QuerySet**: `a model` here means `A`. Isn't it clear?

Comment: Yes yes i got it now :) sorry :) I was thinking in the wrong direction